# Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor will always run on the same system core?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Given a threadpool from `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, will execute all of the requests on the same CPU core/thread or at every task it could pick a new one?

Comment: I've seen a single Java thread be migrated to another core by the system once, so I guess it depends not just on the Java runtime.

Answer (score 4):

A core and a thread are two different things. As far as physical core is concerned, the library documentation of ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't guarantee any such claim to bind a core to a thread. Neither does JVM out of the box provide such low level support to bind a thread to a physical core of the processor.

Binding a process or thread to a processor is known as [*processor affinity*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity). For whatever reason, if you wish to bind a thread to a particular core, you would want to look at this : https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity.

If your question is about thread and whether the same thread will execute all the tasks submitted to a pool? Then not necessarily, based on the idle time of the thread, the pool may terminate and create a new thread to execute a task. I hope this clears your query.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that **if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks**.)...

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The OP did not ask whether it always uses the same Thread, but whether it always uses the same "system core" (whatever that is, probably meant CPU cure).

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the question seems to be based on two wrong assumptions, that a thread always runs on the same core *and* that this executor always uses the same thread. Refuting only one of them is already answering the question. It’s not the preferred one, still, it’s an answer to the question.